# JQUERY AJAX Data overflowing parent element

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Can anyone point me in the right direction. I am appending an HTML element with data from JSON via AJAX call. tis all works fine. I am out putting into a `<ul>` but the `<li>` elements are overflowing outside the parent `<div>`. How can i stop this so the overflow scroll shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with CSS. You will want one of:

```
.myDiv {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

or:

```
.myDiv {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

For the differences, see:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/overflow

Comment: I didnt think it was going to be a CSS issue, over thought the situation. thanks!

Comment: You can also work with overflow-x, overflow-y. This will keep your list bound horizontally and allow vertical scrolling. Horizontal scrolling is typically something to avoid.